# Merge sort usando numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Quiero hacer el algoritmo de merge sort y pasarle un array usando `numpy`, pero la función solo anda al pasarle una lista.

Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de poder hacer que funcione también al pasarle un array con numpy. O alguna otra manera de hacerlo...

```
def mergesort (arreglo):


if len (arreglo) > 1:

    mitad= len (arreglo)//2

    primera_mitad= arreglo[:mitad]

    segunda_mitad= arreglo [mitad:]
    
    # llamada recursiva para ambas 
    mitades
    mergesort (primera_mitad)
    mergesort (segunda_mitad)
    
    # iteradores de ambas mitades
    i= 0
    j= 0
    # iterador principal 
    k= 0
    
    # ordena las dos mitades
    while i < len (primera_mitad ) and j < len (segunda_mitad ):
      if primera_mitad [i] < segunda_mitad[j]:
        arreglo[k] = primera_mitad[i]
        i += 1
      else:
        arreglo[k] = segunda_mitad[j]
        j += 1
      
      k += 1
       
    while i < len (primera_mitad):
      arreglo [k] = primera_mitad[i]
      i += 1
      k += 1
       
    while j < len (segunda_mitad):
      arreglo[k] = segunda_mitad[j]
      j += 1
      k += 1
         
     
    return arreglo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Qué esta pasando

El problema nace de que cuando divides el array en dos mitades en esta línea:

```
primera_mitad= arreglo[:mitad]
segunda_mitad= arreglo [mitad:]
```

el operador de *slice* se comporta de forma ligeramente diferente cuando opera sobre una lista que cuando opera sobre un array numpy (o una tabla pandas, ya puestos).

En una lista lo que retorna es una lista *nueva*, independiente de la anterior. Puedes modificar la sublista que has obtenido con el slice sin afectar a la lista original. En cambio en un array numpy (o una tabla pandas) lo que retorna es una "*vista*" por así decir, del array original, pero esa vista comparte memoria con el array original.

Este ejemplo demuestra lo que digo:

```
# Primero con listas

lista = [1,2,3,4]
trozo = lista[:2]
trozo[0] = 0
print(trozo)
print(lista)
```

produce

```
[0, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

donde se ve que `lista` no ha cambiado por el hecho de cambiar `trozo`

```
# Ahora con arrays numpy
import numpy as np

array = np.array([1,2,3,4])
trozo = array[:2]
trozo[0] = 0
print(trozo)
print(array)
```

produce

```
[0 2]
[0 2 3 4]
```

donde se demuestra que `trozo` no es más que una "ventana" para acceder a un subcojunto de `array`, pero comparten datos. Modificar el trozo modifica el array.

### La solución

Ahora que sabemos lo que pasa, es fácil dar una solución. Necesitamos que esas líneas de tu función hagan una copia independiente de cada mitad. Eso se logra con la siguiente sintaxis:

```
    primera_mitad= arreglo[:mitad].copy()
    segunda_mitad= arreglo[mitad:].copy()
```

Esta sintaxis vale tanto para listas como para arrays numpy, con lo que la función ya ordenará correctamente ambos tipos de datos.

Esto es así deliberadamente por motivos de eficiencia. Ya que numpy o pandas trabajan típicamente sobre arrays muy grandes, los slices permiten recorrer esos arrays de diferentes formas, seleccionar filas y columnas, etc. todo ello sin necesidad de copiar (duplicar) los datos. Además gracias a eso también puedes asignar a través de un slice una selección de filas o columnas del array original.

Comment: Creo que el problema está en tratar a numpy como simples listas, ya vienen funciones para eso: primera_mitad,segunda_mitad =np.array_split(array.flatten(),2) , donde ya obtenes la copia y el slice

Comment: Muchas gracias. @abulafia